# Correct title hierarchy in template

Tags: mediawiki

I try to add titles in a template, which is used at different title levels. But I can't figure out how to make the titles use the correct style.

When I just use a subtitle small enough, it works with the numbering, but the title is in the subtitle 5 for example, but should be in 3.

Example:

My template has something like:

```
==== Title 1 ====

Bla bla

===== Title 2 =====
```

And I use it at various locations, such as

```
==Profile ==

{{MyTemplate}}
```

or:

```
==== Another Profile ====

{{Template}}
```

Comment: Make a template parameter for the toc level.